# c++ send ENTER keyboard_event with Timer as Guard

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard-events

```
std::cout<<"SendKeyBoardEvent "<<keyBEventType<<endl;
// Simulate a key press
  Sleep(200); //in

if (!strcmp(keyBEventType,"ENTER"))
{
    // ENTER key down
      keybd_event(VK_RETURN,0x9C,0,0);
    // ENTER key up
     keybd_event(VK_RETURN,0x9C, 0,0);
}
```

When I run this code from my tool, I must use two keys arrow down and and enter or any other two keys combo except ALT-ENTER. I had used KEY_UP and CONTROL. anyone see my problem here? I appreciate for your help.

**SOLUTION for getch() with Timer as Guard In-Case FTP Transferred(SpecialClient) Forever**

**Either Timer Expire or User Enter Key first**

```
void waitBoostSleep(int seconds) 
{ 
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(seconds)); 
} 

int waitTime(int sec)
{
  waitBoostSleep(sec);
  a->SendKeyBoardEvent("ENTER");
  std::cout<<"TimerExpired after "<<sec<<endl;
  return 0;
}

int StopSicFTPRingBuffer (int TimeInSeconds)
{
boost::thread t66(&waitTime,TimeInSeconds);
if  (getch() == 13)
{
    a->SendKeyBoardEvent("ENTER");
    return 1;
}
t66.join();

return 0;
}
```

**From Main Program**

```
boost::thread t77(&StopSicFTPRingBuffer,45);
system(SicFTPR.str().c_str());                      
t77.join();
```

Sytem will call a special ftp client where it can be interrupted by user with ENTER return.

In-case, someone like me needs this kind of requirements. It worked perfectly for me. 
I had set 45 seconds, if the timer expired, then the ENTER key will execute automatic to stop FTP transferred. If user hit ENTER key first before the timer expired, then FTP transferred will be stopped.

Comment: What is the definition of `keyBEventType` and `keybd_event()`?  I don't see them anywhere in your code.

Comment: @genpfault `keybd_event` is a standard Win32 function

Comment: for the record it's not clear at all what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You weren't doing a keyup, you were doing two key downs. Try this:

```
// ENTER key down
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x9C, 0, 0);

// ENTER key up
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x9C, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,Cris. I did try it before, but my logic in other func is screwed. Thanks. It worked now.                                   `int StopSicFTPRingBuffer (int TimeInSeconds)
{
 int i=0;
 while(i<TimeInSeconds)
 {
    int c;
    FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
  waitTime(1);
  i++;
  c = getch();
  std::cout<<"Waiting-#"<<i<<endl;
  if (i == 10 || c == 13) 
  {
   //Send Enter Key
   a->SendKeyBoardEvent("ENTER");
   break;
  }
 }
 return 0;
}`either i == 10 or getch() == 13, either one is true will send enter Key,but it always stuck getch() waiting for Key

Comment: Is there a way to execute getch(), if (c != 13), then counter keep counting? any advise. I appreciate.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking.

Comment: ... oh fine, I'll just say it. WTF are you on about? Your original question said nothing about an FTP server, or boost, or 9/10 of what you posted, and now you're just throwing that around like we're supposed to know what you're talking about. You need to work on your communication skills.

Comment: Sorry Cris. My question is not clear and it is not related to this post. I should open another post instead. Thanks for your times to answer. Especial it is free. I am really appreciate. Cheers.